# como comparar 2 arrays de objetos sin importar el orden

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Hola a todos tengo el siguiente problema, necesito comparar si 2 arreglos son iguales sin importar el orden del primero, solo necesito validar si los elementos entre sí son iguales, muestro los objetos:

```
const objetoUno = [
    {
        "selection": "Grande",
        "skuId": "npjokd30udxsw0f52t07"
    },
    {
        "selection": "Grande",
        "skuId": "p7kqookeekkctylzh2no"
    },
    {
        "selection": "Rojo",
        "skuId": "c1vf069e1kkip2oaq7wm"
    }
]


const objetoDos = [
    {
        "selection": "Grande",
        "skuId": "p7kqookeekkctylzh2no"
    },
    {
        "selection": "Rojo",
        "skuId": "c1vf069e1kkip2oaq7wm"
    },
    {
        "selection": "Grande",
        "skuId": "npjokd30udxsw0f52t07"
    }
]
```

Nótese en este que en este caso los 2 son iguales la única diferencia es el orden.
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Después de buscar un poco más la solución más sencilla es usar un filter y un some:

```
    let objectFilter = objetoUno.filter(e => {
    return !objetoDos.some(item => item.skuId === e.skuId && item.selection === 
    e.selection);
    });
```

esto devuelve un array con el objeto diferente.